# Call php with onclick (faster loadingtime)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tabs

Im building a Magento platform webshop.

I call a content block in the template with:

```
<a href="#tab">TAB BUTTON</a>
<div id="tab"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('CONTENT'); ?></div>
```

Only the content of getchildhtml is too large to load at once. Is it possible to load the php echo once clicked on the button?

Display-none will still preload the content, but i'm looking too load the php content of getchildhtml.

Comment: You have to do this using ajax. Google it and read what's all about. You can't mix php and javascript like you've tried.

Comment: Before you dive into such a complex and difficult platform like magento - you need to learn how html, js and php work

Comment: Why are you calling an anchor link a button? Your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can but you will need to use AJAX and have a server side script to serve the content

```
  <a href="#tab" id="button">TAB BUTTON</a>
  <div id="tab"></div>

$(function() {
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('#tab').load('_URL_TO_PHP_THAT_ECHO_CONTENT_');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thnx for this answer. I tought of it, but was still looking for the inpossible. I will load an external php file to call the childhtml.